# Return a list with dataframe column values ordered based on another list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a df with columns `a-h`, and I wish to create a list of these column values, but in the order of values in another list (`list1`). `list1` corresponds to the index value in df.

```
df

a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h

list1
[3,1,0,5,2,7,4,6]
```

**Desired list**

```
['d', 'b', 'a', 'f', 'c', 'h', 'e', 'g']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do [`df.columns[list1]`](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/f2638e52.py):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=list('abcdefgh'))

list1 = [3,1,0,5,2,7,4,6]

print(df.columns[list1])
# Index(['d', 'b', 'a', 'f', 'c', 'h', 'e', 'g'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

First get a `np.array` of alphabets

```
arr = np.array(list('abcdefgh'))
```

Or in your case, a list of your `df` columns

```
arr = np.array(df.columns)
```

Then use your indices as a indexing mask

```
arr[[3,1,0]]
```

out:

```
['d', 'b', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
df.columns.to_series()[list1].tolist()
```